# 2 dice are thrown once Find the probability of getting either 1 or 5

Tags: probability

Two dice are thrown once find the probability of getting either 1 or 5 ?

Here I get into a situation that 
I don't understand 
If the answer is 
20 /36 oR it is 2/36 
I m bit confuse between the conditions of union and intersection . 
Or how it is solved??

Comment: How many total possible results are there when you throw two dice?  How many of them have *neither* a $1$ nor a $5$?  Everything that's left over has a $1$ or a $5$ (or both).  That's usually the easiest way to solve this sort of problem.

Comment: As an aside, $\frac{2}{36}$ corresponds to having a $1$ **and** a $5$ simultaneously.  Remember that $A\cap B = \{x~:~x\in A~\text{and}~x\in B\}$.  In terms of events it is those outcomes where $A$ *and* $B$ simultaneously are true.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you throw one die then the other. This is ultimately a meaningless assumption as we could just call them Die 1 and 2 respectively, but throwing them in order makes more sense for the explanation.

Let's suppose on the first die you score a $1$ or $5$. There is a $\frac13$ probability of this (agreed?), and the second die doesn't matter.

Then, we suppose you do *not* score a $1$ or $5$ on your first die. There's a $\frac 23$ probability of this, then a $\frac13$ probability of winning on the second throw (agreed?). So winning this way has a probability of $\frac23 \cdot \frac13 =\frac 29$

Thusly the total probability of success is $\frac13+\frac29=\frac59$

The key to these problems is to *either* add up  the ways you win, *or* subtract the ways you lose from $1$.

Answer (score 2):

And to answer the question in the other way (as suggested by my comment), there is a $2/3$ chance that the first die is neither a $1$ nor a $5$ and also a $2/3$ chance that the second die is neither a $1$ nor a $5$.  These are independent events, so to find the probability that both occur you just multiply them:

$$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}.$$

This is the probability that you get **neither** a $1$ nor a $5$ on either die, so the probability that you get either a $1$ or a $5$ on at least one die is $1-4/9 = 5/9$.

Answer (score 1):

This one is union.  $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, where $A$ is the event of a $1$ or $5$ on the first roll, $B$ that of a $1$ or $5$ on the second roll.

$P(A)=P(B)=\frac26=\frac13$.  $P(A\cap B)=\frac13\cdot \frac13=\frac19$.

Thus $P(A\cup B)=\frac13+\frac13-\frac19=\frac59$.

Another way of describing it is that there are $36$ possible outcomes and $16$ with neither a $1$ or $5$.  Thus $1-\frac{16}{36}=\frac{20}{36}=\frac59$.